# modulo string additions interacting between print lines

Tags: python, string, modulo

Im printing 2 lines that both use \r and % to replace a either %d or %s in their own print lines. Problem is they seam to get crossed over with one another.

```
def pinging():
    average_list = []
    max_list = []
    host_list = host_string(ptype)
    numberitems = len(host_list)
    counter = 0

    for i in range(0,len(host_list)):
        counter += 1
        print('Pinged:%d' % i,"of",numberitems, end='\r')
        try:
            ping = subprocess.check_output(['ping','-c',num_pings,host_list[i]],timeout=sec_timeout)
        except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
            print('Timeout:%s' % host_list[i], end="\r")
            continue

        ping = str(ping)
        ravg,rmax = string_configure(ping,host_list[i],num_pings)
        average_list.append(ravg)
        max_list.append(rmax)
    return(average_list,max_list)
```

I was expecting 2 separate updating print lines:
`1 of 25` #and so one
`Timeout: 12.34.56.78` #and so on

Instead i get:
`0 of 25`

`1 of 25.25.109` # it continue like this replacing the "numberitems" with an altered ip address from "host_list"

So how do i stop these 2 print lines from interacting?

Comment: Why not use `str.format()` or better yet, **f-strings**? Modulo string formatting is ‘out dated’ and has been replaced with more robust functionality.

Comment: how does .format() work with replacing values on a single line? I tried to use it but i could seam to get it to replace values on a single line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `\r` only moves the cursor back to the beginning of the line but does not erase it so the next print will just write above what was already written but won't erase the next characters so you will get a mix of the two lines.

`"\033[F"` is a special sequence to move your cursor to the line above in the console.

So after the two `print` you can add

```
print("\033[F\033[F", end="")
```

That will move the cursor two lines up which means that the two lines will be displayed together without one crossing the other.

You should also remove the `end="\r"` in your `print` if you want this to work.

Comment: Be careful that you need to move 2 lines up only if the two print were displayed, otherwise you just need to move 1 line up

Comment: This could work if i also had the alternative for moving the cursor down in the console, because currently it just continues to shift up the console with only moving up

Comment: Well if it moves up, it is because you don't have the same amount of \n than \033[F. Are you sure you have removed the `end="\r"`. By default the print function puts \n at the end of the line

Comment: Okay yeah this worked thanks, i used \033[A and \033[B instead to move the cursor up and down and this worked great thanks again